# Realizando uma consulta linq C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tenho um controller onde faço um `Select` para obter uma lista, porém o mesmo retorna vazio.

```
public IEnumerable<Check> GetUserByNumberOfregistration(int numberOfregistrationUser)
{
    CheckContext contextObj = new CheckContext();

    var result = contextObj.hour
        .Where(x => x.NumberOfregistrationUser == numberOfregistrationUser)
        .Select(p => new Check()
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            ArrivalTime = p.ArrivalTime,
            DepartureTime = p.DepartureTime,
            NumberOfregistrationUser = p.NumberOfregistrationUser
        });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Complicado saber o porque disso só com esse código.

Comment: '((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<AppTeste.Models.Check>)result).Sql' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Comment: @Gvr Conseguiu resolver já?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque seu result é do tipo `dbquery`. Você tem que executar a query após o Where ou o Select utilizando o método `ToList()` para retornar uma coleção, ou o método `FirstOrDefault()` para retornar apenas um objeto.

Para seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
public IEnumerable<Check> GetUserByNumberOfregistration(int numberOfregistrationUser)
{ 
    CheckContext contextObj = new CheckContext();
    var result = contextObj.hour
                           .Where(x => x.NumberOfregistrationUser == numberOfregistrationUser) 
                           .Select(p => new Check() { Id = p.Id, ArrivalTime = p.ArrivalTime, DepartureTime = p.DepartureTime, NumberOfregistrationUser = p.NumberOfregistrationUser })
                           .ToList(); 
    return result;
}
```